# Sharing game progress through social media sprite kit / swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, sprite-kit, share

How would I create a button that allows the user to share their high score on social media? For example, flappy bird had a button that allowed that led the user straight to twitter saying "I just scored 15 on flappy bird! #FlappyBird" or whatever their high score is. I have created a label and have a block of code that runs when the user taps it, but I have no clue where to start with the rest.

Comment: I would rather see you helped to learn to solve your problems than given a ready-made solution: have you tried anything? If so, please tell is what, __in your question__.

Comment: I have not tried anything, I have no clue where to start. Could you give me a tip or how to start accomplishing this? @PJTraill

Answer (score 1):

In a SKScene:

```
let textToShare = "I just did \(labelScore) on the game! Try to beat me, it's free!"

            let objectsToShare = [textToShare]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

            let currentViewController:UIViewController=UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!

            currentViewController.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to open the share menu on iOS and let the user decide where to share.

```
        let textToShare = "cool text"

        let objectsToShare = [textToShare]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer I've given for Twitter sharing in Sprite Kit.  This is using objective-c.  But I do agree with PJTrail that you should make an effort to learn how it is done instead of just copy/ pasting the code.  That way you can edit it for your own needs in the future.

Link: [Twitter share button in a sprite-kit game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460212/is-it-possible-to-have-a-twitter-facebook-share-button-in-a-sprite-kit-game/24879343#24879343)